# Removing formatting from a link in a list item

Tags: html, css, list, colors, hover

I have the classic configuration of a list containing a number of links, nicely formatted with CSS. Unfortunately, the list items, which should change colour when hovered over (using a li:hover), stay formatted as links (blue if unclicked, purple if clicked, underlined).
How would I get the browser to ignore the formatting of the link and use the formatting from above- or should I just edit the links themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the formatting to the link tag as well, like this:

```
li:hover, li:hover a
{
   ...
}
```